# Google can't access my page due to robots.txt but the testing tool says it's OK

Tags: robots.txt, crawl-errors, disallow

My robots.txt is the typical that allows all bots everywhere

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

When I test it with Google tool everything is OK.

[image: robots.txt no errors]

But in Google Search Console I get an error that my site can't be accessed.

[image: robots.txt unable to access page]

Can somebody help?

Comment: `User-agent: * Disallow: /` does not "allow all bots everywhere". It blocks all bots from accessing your home page.

Comment: More than just the home page. It Blocks the whole site.

Comment: OMG i was so tired that i put disallow instead of allow.
Thank you
If i let allow / disallow line empty ,is it ok ? 
I think so.

Answer (score 1):

> When I test it with Google tool everything is ok.

The tool is simply telling you that the file is syntactically valid. Whether it blocks (or allows) traffic is another matter.

> But in Google Search Console I get an error that my site can't be accessed.
>
> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /
> ```

As already mentioned in comments, this **blocks everything** and allows nothing! To allow everything (the *default* action) you should remove the `/` (slash) on the `Disallow:` line:

```
 User-agent: *
 Disallow:
```

Or simply remove all the directives (or even the file itself).